# Webkit.Net wait for page to be fully loaded

Tags: c#, webkit

I'm trying to make an C# windows form application, with an webbrowser.

I'm using the webkit browser:  [Link to the browser](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/)

The webbrowser did i put in an class file, so i can acces it through all the forms i'm going to use.

The code that's generate the webbrowser:

```
public static WebKit.WebKitBrowser mainBrowser = new WebKitBrowser();
```

I'm having this piece of code that give's some problems:

```
globalVars.mainBrowser.Navigate("http://www.somesite.com/");
while (globalVars.mainBrowser.IsBusy)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
globalVars.mainBrowser.Document.GetElementById("user").TextContent = "User Name";
```

But it's not working. If i do an message box after the while, it shows up before it's possible to render the page...

So what is the best way to wait until the site is fully loaded?

**UPDATE 1**

In an standalone class file, am i making the webkit controll like this:

```
public static WebKit.WebKitBrowser mainBrowser = new WebKitBrowser();
```

And in an form, i've got now this code (thanks to Tearsdontfalls):

```
public void loginthen()
    {
        globalVars.mainBrowser.DocumentCompleted += mainBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        globalVars.mainBrowser.Navigate("http://www.somesite.com/");    
    }

void mainBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var send = sender as WebKit.WebKitBrowser;
    if (send.Url == e.Url)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Inloggen");
        globalVars.mainBrowser.Document.GetElementById("user").TextContent = "User Name";
    }
 }
```

But no messagebox shows up. But if i use an local (on the same form) webkit browser, i'm getting te MessageBox. But then the user field isn't filled in.

Even an breakpoint in the documentCompleted event, isn't triggerd. So it looks like the event listner isn't working...

So why is it not working?

Comment: Maybe document completed event is an option?

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls, mayby. But how would the code looks like then? because the form i'm doing this from isn't always on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create an event listener on the Document Completed Event on your Webbrowser, or you can create it dynamically like that:

```
globalVars.mainbrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(mainbrowser_DocumentCompleted);
```

Where `mainbrowser_DocumentCompleted` is the name of the void where you can do sth like this(I used the names of your provided code):

```
void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    var send = sender as WebKit.WebKitBrowser;
    if (send.Url == e.Url) {
        globalVars.mainBrowser.Document.GetElementById("user").TextContent = "User Name";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but if i do an MessageBox in the if statement of the event, it doesn't show up...

I'll update the question with some more info..

Comment: Ok I updated the code(added new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted) to add event handler). Maybe this does the trick, if not: do you have any Code in the Navigating/Navigate Event, which could cancel the browsing?

Comment: It still not getting to the breakpoint (wich i set on the line `var send = sender....`

And i don't have any other code than i have in the updated question (about the webbrowser then)

Does i have to do some things first by the webkit browser itself before it can browse??? (note, i don't show it anywhere on the form)

Comment: Do you know if the webbrowser is really browsing? Do you made the webbrowser visible somewhere/added to the control list of you from(maybe it has to be visible to be working)

Comment: Done that now, and now it fires the breakpoint...

So if i've got the webbrowser added to the form, it works... But if i do everyting (the login) and close the form and open an other form, will the webbrowser still be logged in???

Comment: If it works like GeckoFX and the .Net webbrowser, it will store the cookies, so you would be logged in on another form.

Comment: Alright then. In that case, i will work with this (set visible on false and done :D)

Thank you verry much for your help and patience!

Comment: I hope you've got an little patiant over... The value of the input field with ID 'user' isn't changed... It's stil empty. But it doens't give any errors or something like that...

Comment: Im patient, do you removed the if part of the code? This is important, because document completed is firing everytime when a (i)frame was loaded. If not, Id suggest to let this part run over JS, im sure that there is a method to run your own JS in the webkitBrowser

Comment: The if statement is still in it, and that works, because an messagebox in it fires.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following piece of code let the events fire when the browser is in invisible mode.

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(webKitBrowser.Width, webKitBrowser.Height))
{
    webKitBrowser.DrawToBitmap(
        bmp, 
        new Rectangle(
            webKitBrowser.Location.X, 
            webKitBrowser.Location.Y, 
            webKitBrowser.Width, 
            webKitBrowser.Height
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. It's a couple of years later, and I don't have the specific project for hand so I can't test it. But maybe this will help somebody in the future!

Comment: Of course, that's the point I have added in. I have figured this around after a bit of trail n error. Strange though it doesn't allow the events to fire. I am using this as a part of non windows application.